# Automatically mark required fields with an asterisk, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to detect the required fields in a mongoid model in order to add a mark after the label in the view. This is the initializer I'm using. Note that the only different thing for Mongoid is `Mongoid::Validations::PresenceValidator`, in ActiveRecord would be `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator`, so maybe it's not a mongoid-related question (?):

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  alias :orig_label :label

  # add a 'required' CSS class to the field label if the field is required
  def label(method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options && content_or_options.class == Hash
      options = content_or_options
    else
      content = content_or_options
    end

    if object.class.validators_on(method).map(&:class).include? Mongoid::Validations::PresenceValidator

      if options.class != Hash
        options = {:class => "required"}
      else
        options[:class] = ((options[:class] || "") + " required").split(" ").uniq.join(" ")
      end
    end

    self.orig_label(method, content, options || {}, &block)
  end
end
```

Also, I'm using this style in order to include an asterisk in the lable.required:

```
 /* add required field asterisk */
 label.required:after {
     content: " *";
 }
```

If I set the required class in the label manually, it is shown successfully. The problem is that the FormBuilder is not modifying the label at all, and no marks are shown. It seems like the file is not used at all, I'm including it as an initializer, but event writting a simple `puts "I am here..."` it's not shown in the server console.

What am I missing?

Thank your for your answers in advance.

Comment: Isnt it ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, maybe could be your rails version.

"In Rails 4 the validations class has been changed to ActiveRecord. So replacing ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator with ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator should do the trick."

source: http://blog.pothoven.net/2012/10/self-marking-required-fields-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Try extending

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I first thought I was a dumb, this easy thing! But later I've seen it doesn't work, it says `FormHelper is not a class (TypeError)`. Anyway, I've seen many examples using FormBuilder, like this one: https://gist.github.com/jordanandree/9d6812f0c99a20cacb2c